# How to change the Snippet path in ACE-EDITOR

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I am having different snippet files to load in editor.
But I don't know where to specify the snippet path.

In javascript,I am just setting the mode.

`editor.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');`

Please help me out to set the snippet path

Answer (score 1):

use `ace.config.setModuleUrl("ace/snippets/javascript", "some-path")`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.